# Are deeds recorded where angels don't go?

Tags: malaikah

I have read that angels do not enter any building where there are photographs or dogs.  If this is true, then what happens to the angels that record my good and bad deeds?  When I enter a building that has photographs or dogs, are my good and bad deeds still being recorded?

Answer (score 4):

> I have read that angels do not enter any building where there are photographs or dogs.

I doubt the authenticity of what is said, because if it were true then one could simply place a dog or a picture in a dying person's room and to prevent him from dying (I could be wrong here). and angel of death is definitely an angel of mercy, if not then calling [euthanasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthanasia) "mercy-killing" would be wrong or debatable.

> If this is true, then what happens to the angels that record my good and bad deeds?

Considering what is said was true. Those angels could be commissioned for something else, like worship or praise Him, or log somebody else's deeds. It is also necessary to know that [Kiraman Katibin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiraman_Katibin) are not fixed for a particular person for his entire life span and are changeable Like e.g. it is said (reference would be appreciated) when a person repents and supplicates for forgiveness Allah forgives and also changes these angels and never commissions them back to log that persons actions again.

> When I enter a building that has photographs or dogs, are my good and bad deeds still being recorded?

To answer this question I'll quote an excerpt from [Du`a Kumayl](http://supplications.al-islam.org/adiya/dua-kumayl.php):

> 173 And every evil act which You have commanded the Noble Writers to record,
>
> 174 Those whom You have appointed to watch over what appears from me
>
> 175 And whom You have made, along with my bodily members, witness against me.
>
> 176 And *“You were Yourself the Watcher” (5:117)* over me from behind them,
>
> 177 And *the Witness of what is hidden from them*

And Quran's verse [5:177](http://tanzil.net/#5:117) which is referenced above:

> I said not to them except what You commanded me - to worship Allah, my Lord and your Lord. And I was a witness over them as long as I was among them; but when You took me up, You were the Observer over them, and *You are, over all things, Witness.*

Which means no action, thought and/or intention can go by without having been *Witnessed*.

Answer (score 1):

The hadith, Which Explicitly mentions this issue is:

> [Sahih al-Bukhari 3225](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/36), Narrated Abu Talha:
>
> I heard Allah's Apostle   saying; "Angels (of Mercy) do not enter a
>   house wherein there is a dog or a picture of a living creature (a
>   human being or an animal)."

So clearly it mentioned about the angels of Mercy, and Not every angel.

Comment: The hadith only mentions angels without specifying - here is a link to the original text (Arabic) http://dorar.net/hadith?skeys=%D9%84%D8%A7+%D8%AA%D8%AF%D8%AE%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%83%D8%A9+%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA%D8%A7+%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87+%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A8&st=a&xclude=